# how can i do math to items in a list in python?

Tags: python

I have this test file:

```
123 52 65 75 
40 58 34 8

98 89 89 98 
45 34 29 49
```

and I would like to take every two numbers and multiply them together. I'm having some issues. I know I should do some kind of assignment, where I would start at x=0 and end at x+= 1 with a counter and everything, but I need help on getting started.

Here's what I have so far:

I have a file that's full of numbers and I want to take every three numbers in the file, add them together, and then divide that by 2. Here's what I have so far:

```
text= input('file: ')
f = open(text, 'r')
for line in f:
    counter = 0
    for n in line:
        counter *= int(n)
    print(counter)
```

This multiplies all of the numbers in the line together, but I just want every two. I feel like I'm close but need some advice.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I want to get 624 4875, and so forth, just have them multiplied and such.

Comment: what if a line contain 5 numbers?

Comment: Plz clarify **take every two numbers and multiply them together** or **take every two numbers of a line and multiply them together** . And also your expected output

Comment: then it would ignore it, i suppose

Comment: Ahsanul, I want every two numbers per line to be multiplied.

Comment: Does it really multiply all the numbers together? It looks more like it would start with 0, multiply by each individual character in the line (e.g. `1`, `2`, then `3` instead of `123`), stay at 0, and then crash when it gets to a space.

Comment: I added a new example to the top of my answer.  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

As Pieter said, you can do it in a list comprehension.

For beginners, I think `for` loops are easier to read. Calling `enumerate()` on your object gives you an iterator.

```
line = [4, 5, 7, 8]
product = 1
# loop_number counts up from 1
for loop_number, value in enumerate(line, start=1):
    print('LOOP_NUMBER_(ITERATOR)_IS: ' + str(loop_number))
    product *= value
    print('PRODUCT IS NOW: ' + str(product))
    if loop_number % 2 == 0:
        print('OUTPUT PRODUCT: ' + str(product))
        product = 1
```

Output:

```
LOOP_NUMBER_(ITERATOR)_IS: 1
PRODUCT IS NOW: 4
LOOP_NUMBER_(ITERATOR)_IS: 2
PRODUCT IS NOW: 20
OUTPUT PRODUCT: 20
LOOP_NUMBER_(ITERATOR)_IS: 3
PRODUCT IS NOW: 7
LOOP_NUMBER_(ITERATOR)_IS: 4
PRODUCT IS NOW: 56
OUTPUT PRODUCT: 56
```

Comment: What does iterator mean?  enumerate?  Should I take a course in physics first?

Comment: Nothing to do with physics, lol. An iterator is something that "counts" (iterates, increments) each time you go through a loop.

Enumerate is just a built-in python function that gives you the `loop_number` in addition to the `value` while you loop.

Comment: I edited the answer, hopefully that's a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to take every two numbers and multiply them together.

It's always best to post:

1. Your starting data.
2. The actual results you want

If you want to multiply pairs of numbers together, like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]

1 * 2 => 2
3 * 4 => 12
```

then you can do this:

```
import csv
import itertools as it

with open('data.txt', newline='') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')

    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row)   #=> ['1', '2', '3', '4']

        every_other0 = it.islice(row, 0, False, 2)  #Produces items from the row at index 0, 2, etc.
        every_other1 = it.islice(row, 1, False, 2)  #Produces items from the row at index 1, 3, etc.

        while True:
            str1 = next(every_other0, None)  #if there are no more items in every_other0, return False
            str2 = next(every_other1, None)  #if there are no more items in every_other1, return False

            if str1 and str2:  #if either str1 or str2 is False, the condition is False
                num1 = int(str1)
                num2 = int(str2)
                print("{} * {} = {}".format(num1, num2, num1*num2))
            else:
                break
```

---

```
$ cat data.txt
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8

~/python_programs$ python3.4 prog.py
['1', '2', '3', '4']
1 * 2 = 2
3 * 4 = 12
['5', '6', '7', '8']
5 * 6 = 30
7 * 8 = 56
```

---

Based on your code here:

```
counter = 0
for n in line:
    counter *= int(n)
```

maybe you want something like the following:

```
import operator as op
import functools as funcs
import csv

with open('data.txt', newline='') as f:  #opens the file and automatically closes the file when the block is exited for any reason--including if an exception occurs
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')

    for row in csv_reader:
        every_other = [int(item) for item in row[::2] ] #=> row[::2] is equivalent to row[0:len(row):2], which means get the element at index 0, then add the step, 2, to the index value, and get the next element, etc., and stop at the index len(row).
        print(every_other)
```

---

```
[1, 1, 1]
```

---

```
        result = funcs.reduce(op.mul, every_other)  #multiply all the numbers in every_other together, reducing them to one number
        print(result)
```

---

```
1
```

---

```
        every_other = [int(item) for item in row[1::2] ] #=> row[1::2] is equivalent to row[1:len(row):2], which means start at index 1 and stop at a the end of row, and get the element at index 1; add the step, 2, to the index value, and get the element at that index, etc. 
        print(every_other)
```

---

```
[2, 2, 2]
```

---

```
        result = funcs.reduce(op.mul, every_other)
        print(result)
```

---

```
8
```

Answer (score -1):

Using an inline for.
Something like this?

```
[line[n] * line[n+1] for range(0,len(line),2)]
```

Comment: An "inline for" is called a comprehension, and I think yours is missing a few things. Try this in an interpreter session to fix the multiple errors.